# IPython notebook launched, but cannot login via Browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to Login my Notebook via Browser, but Chrome shows "This webpage is not available"
I have the following on my terminal:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-217 .ipython]$ ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
[I 11:31:38.289 NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/ec2-user/anaconda/.ipython/profile_nbserver'
[I 11:31:38.295 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 11:31:38.310 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ec2-user/anaconda/.ipython
[I 11:31:38.311 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 11:31:38.311 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 11:31:38.311 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Can someone helps figure out what there is 0 active kernels? I have add the following  in my ipython_nootbook_config.py file

```
#kernel config
c.IPkernelApp.pylab='inline' # if you want plotting support always

#Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile=u'/home/ec2-user/anaconda/certificates/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.ip='*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser=False
c.NotebookApp.password=u'sha1:0d4773e470e5:2a91dcf5a15875f15c4ad18f9d3
4c95be563f804'
#It is a good idea to put it on a known, fixed port
c.NotebookApp.port=8888
#-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of running kernel has nothing to do with that. 
Which page Are you visiting ? `http://<ip>:8888` ? did you forgot the `s` in `https` ? Do you have Proxy settings ? Sophos antivirus ? On a Company network ?